# Q re: Terminal scripting in OS X

Tags: macos

This is a question concerning an older post.

The original link is here:

[Terminal scripting in OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187124/terminal-scripting-in-osx)

The file suggested by khachik is:

```
    #!/bin/sh

     show=`defaults read com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles 2>/dev/null`

    if [ "$show" == "TRUE" ]; then
    defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE
    else # here we come, if it is FALSE or is empty (the default)
    defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
    fi

    killall Finder
```

I got this to work by typing it out in TextWrangler and saving it as a text file with a '.command' suffix. It runs as a double-clickable routine, opening a new Terminal window as it runs.

I originally began typing it in Terminal's 'nano' editor, but that somehow disappeared and the Terminal prompt changed to a single caret ('>'). I assumed that one of the Mac's built in languages was activated. I finished typing it in, but it would not run.

My question is a) in what language is the above script in? and b) is there any way to know which language the Terminal activated? I typed 'which language' but got no answer.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's the prompt bash uses when you've entered part of a multiline command, and it's asking for the next line.  Basically, you started something that you haven't finished.  It might be that you didn't close a quote, or an `if` statement, or something like that.

Try typing `"` and hitting return, and you'll see that prompt.  Type another `"` and hit return again, and it'll complain about an invalid command (and go back to the normal prompt).

Comment: I did what you suggest and that clears things up a bit. Thanks for the response